# Execute file rather than parse it

Tags: python

I am using Python to parse some files and it turns out one of the files is, itself, a Python script. I need to find elements in a list and the list is specifically defined. The file I'm parsing contains a line like:

`THESE_VALUES = ["Value1", "vAlue2", "VaLUE4"]`

I can use *my* Python script to parse the "'s in this line and get each individual entry, but it might be just as easy to take that line and let it execute in my script to create my own `THESE_VALUES` array. Is this possible?

If this is not possible, or ill-advised, what is the easiest/most pythonic way to get these strings?

NOTE: This line is completely trusted and I do not need to worry about executing bad/improper commands.

Comment: yes, it is possible with `exec` ... just highly frowned upon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval` since you trust completely your input (you've been warned):

```
>>> s = 'THESE_VALUES = ["Value1", "vAlue2", "VaLUE4"]'
>>> eval(s.split('=', 1)[1])
['Value1', 'vAlue2', 'VaLUE4']
```

With the above code, we split at the first `=` and we evaluate the expression following the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, once you've parsed the string you can use `exec` to evaluate the string as a python command:

`exec('THESE_VALUES = ["Value1", "vAlue2", "VaLUE4"]')`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
def getValues(str_values):
    l = locals()
    exec(str_values)
    return l['THESE_VALUES']

getValues('THESE_VALUES = ["Value1", "vAlue2", "VaLUE4"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the line starting with `"THESE_VALUES = "`, you can use `ast.literal_eval` after splitting:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("in.py") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("THESE_VALUES"):
              print(literal_eval(line.split("=",1)[1].strip()))
              break
['Value1', 'vAlue2', 'VaLUE4']
```

Comment: Add 1 as second parameter to split...There may be another = in the input

Comment: @JuniorCompressor, yep, cheers,  thought I already had it in there.